# Internal calls issues asterisk vicidial

Tags: linux, voip, asterisk, telephony

I have just installed new Vicidial v7.0.3 on an i7 12 GB Ram pc I have completed all steps in the installation including OS-install, network configuration, Firewall set to internal on one of the network card can ping internally as well as to ping outside, vicibox-express installation is done, I have created few user's and phones using vicidial admin.php interface, no sip carriers and dial plan being setup yet, I have configured all extension on different SNOM 710 phones so when I call local phone extension I get message the extension 291 is not available and it goes in to voicemail, can someone please help out with this situation. I have noticed one weird error thing which may not be normal as per shown below

7 11:30:05] -- Executing [291@default:1] Dial("SIP/298-00000002", "SIP/291|60|") in new stack [Feb 7 11:30:05] WARNING[4345][C-00000002]: pbx.c:1682 pbx_exec: The application delimiter is now the comma, not the pipe. Did you forget to convert your dialplan? (Dial(SIP/291|60|))

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Asterisk CLI should be telling you why the phone is not ringing, I'm guessing the phone is not registered to the Asterisk server, take a closer look to the phone config.

About the Warning:

> [Feb 7 11:30:05] WARNING[4345][C-00000002]: pbx.c:1682 pbx_exec: The application delimiter is now the comma, not the pipe. Did you forget to convert your dialplan? (Dial(SIP/291|60|))

It looks like the Asterisk version configured in VICIdial and the actual Asterisk version running is not the same. This would fix the WARNING in your call attempts.

Get the running version:

```
# asterisk -rx "core show version"
```

Then go to Admin -> Servers in the GUI and set the value "Asterisk Version" to the one you got in the previous step.

If you don't have a server in this section, you need to add one. Make sure to set the right version, activate the "Active Asterisk Server" and set it to active, you should also read every option in the server.

Hope you get it working.

Comment: Done that was it asterisk version was wrong in admin --> server I have corrected it and boom it's working, Thank you.